# Balcony composting - suggestions for trapped rainwater

Tags: compost, urban-gardening

I have an apartment with a balcony - the flooring of the balcony is a lot of wood boards.

My compost bin is a big plastic recycling bin which I have perforated with an awl and rubber hammer on the bottom and sides.

What this means is that when it rains (anything beyond a sprinkle), I have a real hard time turning the compost enough to encourage that water out of the bin.

If I have newspaper around I shred and toss some in to soak up a bit of the water.

My question is if there's any better material I could use to try and absorb the water a bit more. A few days of sun will eventually dry it out, but generally the water really gets trapped between the compost and wood boards, no matter how perforated the bottom is.

**edit**: I do have a cover and have used as suggested Ed here. This appears to work well barring heavy rain. I have also place bricks under the corners of the bin, which has drained a little water and provided some more aeration.

All the same, I would like to keep the question open a bit longer as I'm still interested in the question of some organic material which may be able to absorb some of this moisture.

**Many thanks** for your help as the bin is already operating better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put the container in a container. Think about a flower pot and the dish it sits on. Same idea. Can you not cover the recycling bin?

Comment: I could cover it (cover is perforated) but leaving the top on introduces more aeration problems for me. Taking it on and off requires anticipating rainfall (not hard, just a never ending task).  A container in a container could work, but it seems like the water would still collect in the compost bin -- not sure however.

Comment: What about putting your recycling bin on a pallet or on a couple bricks to promote air flow?

Comment: This was what I actually ended up doing, and it helps a great deal with aeration and moisture. Although @Grady pulp cartons are handy if available.

Answer (score 7):

I'd put a cover on it that's easy to remove , and can be propped open on one side.  For a McGuyver example, duct-tape a cover to one side, and duct-tape a prop-up stick to the other side of the cover that will hold it open, lean-to-fashion (while still keeping rain out) most of the time.  Be sure to consider wind as needed in your situation.  The cover should open down-wind for the usual wind direction *in that particular spot* for storms.  Make sure that the side that's attached to the bin extends beyond the bin's edge, so the rain will drain off outside the bin.

Answer (score 3):

As for materials that absorb water, in my worm bins, I use:
Peat moss, cardboard, formed pulp cartons: like egg cartons, drink holders, packing material etc.